# mono obfuscator for non-window os

Tags: c#, macos, mono, obfuscation

Are there any mono obfuscation programs out there that can run on mac os x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of command line tools:

- [NCloak](http://code.google.com/p/ncloak/)
- [Obfuscar](http://code.google.com/p/obfuscar/) (seems a bit dead)
- A derivative from [Obfuscar](http://code.google.com/p/obfuscar/) maintained by [RemObjects](http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/mh/2010/01/12/p303).

Answer (score 1):

[Eziriz .NET Obfuscator](http://www.eziriz.com/net_obfuscator.htm) (part of their .NET Reactor tool suite) seems to work for Mono on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Just find one that is written for the .NET platform and use that under mono.

There are many of them around (top 2 hits from Google):

http://rustemsoft.com/downloadSkater.htm

http://www.9rays.net/Category/53-spices_net_suite.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Babel Obfuscator](https://babelfor.net) can run on [MAC OSX](https://babelfor.net/News/Details/34) and support all major platforms included Mono.

DISCLAIMER: I am the developer of Babel Obfuscator.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but that link seems to be to a site with a bad SSL setup.

Answer (score -1):

[Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) supports this - as long as your original assemblies can run on Mac OS X using Mono, the obfuscated assemblies till run too.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developer of Crypto Obfuscator.

Comment: He asked for a obfuscator that can run on non-window OS

Comment: @Sergi the question asked explicitly for Mac OS X